# Healthkit Background Delivery Calling Multiple Times in seconds

Tags: ios, swift, background-process, healthkit

I have an app running the below code to get Healthkit data every hour when the app is in the background/suspened/terminated and it is running every hour without fail as desired.The code is called from appdelgate

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

However it is actually triggering the query 3-6 times every hour all in under a second thus data is hitting my server 3-6 times more than needed.

I have read plenty of questions about background delivery from health kit but none seem to cover this issue.

I have read that it could be because i am registering for background refresh every time and i should be checking if i have already registered and not re-registering but i don't know how to check and can't find any doc reference that even mentions this process. I also don't know if this is the issue given that the number of times the code runs each hour is so variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 func startObservingKJ() {
     print("BG Code Called")
     let KJQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)!
     self.healthStore.enableBackgroundDelivery(for: KJQuantityType, frequency: .hourly) { (success, error) in
         if let unwrappedError = error {
             print("could not enable background delivery KJ: \(unwrappedError)")
         }
         if success {
             print("background delivery enabled KJ")
         }
     }


     let query = HKObserverQuery(sampleType: KJQuantityType, predicate: nil) { (query, completionHandler, error) in


        self.updateKJandSteps() {
             completionHandler()
         }


     }
     healthStore.execute(query)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally realised that the query was exciting the `self.updateKJandSteps()` multiple times as there were multiple entries being returned by the query. I added a check to ensure that `self.updateKJandSteps()` was not already running and this fixed the issue with only one update now taking place.

Comment: Can you explain how you did this? I am experiencing the same problem, my observerquery fires its handler once per step record added to HealthKit and is causing a lot of static with records that eventually get ignored by my server as duplicates.